# PHP: Count input type with value

Tags: php, html

Hi I want to count input type with value

```html
<input type="text" name="a[]" value="Test1">
<input type="text" name="a[]" value="Test2">
<input type="text" name="a[]" value="">
```

PHP Code:

```
echo count($_POST['a']);
```

The output is **3**. I want to get only the input type with value which is **2**.

I want my output to be **2**

Thank you

Comment: its a build-in function you can't change its behavior. But you can remove the empty value bu iteration

Comment: try `count(array_filter($_POST['a']))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work -

```
count(array_filter($_POST['a']))
```

`array_filter` will remove the empty values from array.

[array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)